# application/json request to curl command line for reproduction

Tags: python, curl

Is there a library/tool out there to convert raw application/json requests to curl command line (like show code in postman, or the curl in openapi).

Simple example under with just json:

```
---------------- request ----------------
POST https://xxxx.yyyy.zzzz/idpro-test-api/mid/business
User-Agent: python-requests/2.27.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
accept: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 86

{"user_id": "987000205", "ssn": "21010008287", "mid_issuer_id": 32, "activate": false}
---------------- response ----------------
<deleted example of a 500 I like to reproduce>
------------------------------------------
```

curl.exe in powershell (needs to escape the double-quotes):

```
curl.exe -vv -X POST -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 "https://xxxx.yyyy.zzzz/idpro-test-api/mid/business" \
 -d '{\"user_id\": \"987000205\", \"ssn\": \"21010008287\", \"mid_issuer_id\": 32, \"activate\": false}'
```

curl in linux bash:

```
curl -vv -X POST -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json"  \
 "https://xxxx.yyyy.zzzz/idpro-test-api/mid/business" \
 -d '{"user_id": "987000205", "ssn": "21010008287", "mid_issuer_id": 32, "activate": false}'
```

Answer (score -1):

I found curlify which is exactly what I want: https://github.com/ofw/curlify, (why cant pyCurl mention this on their site).